# How to display axis on the image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a question how to display axis x and y that they will be visible on the image ?

I would be appreciate for any help please.

[image]

Comment: plot? just plot

Comment: yes, I want to use plot or line. But I don't know what can I use it to plot line like that.